# Showing that $\exists c \in [a,b] \space$ such that $f^{(n)} = 0$

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f: [a,b] \to R$ be n-times differenitable with distinct roots ${r_{1}...r_{n}}$. Show that $\exists c \in [a,b] \space$ such that $f^{(n)} = 0$.

I know I'm supposed to use the MVT or Rolle's Theorem, but I'm just not sure where to start with this proof.

Also, when they say "n-times differentiable", are they just referring to the degree of the function, or how many times it can be derivated until the derivative is 0?

Comment: Shouldn't there be $n+1$  roots? This would fail for $n=1$ otherwise.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but the question explicitly states that there are {${r_{1}...r_{n}}$} roots.

Comment: This statement is quite clearly incorrect then. For $f(x) = x$ on the interval $[-0.5,0.5]$, has a root $0$, but its derivative is identically $1$, and so vanishes nowhere.

Comment: It's not true for $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$ as $f^{(n)}(x)=n!\ne0$.  Suggest you check the question with your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n+1$ roots (not $n$), you can re-apply Rolle's theorem several times, till you get to $f^{(n)}$

According to Rolle's theorem there are n points where f' is zero (one between each consecutive roots), therefore there are (n-1) points where f" is zero, etc. Note that the sum of derivative's order and number of points is always (n+1). Finally you get 1 point where $f^{(n)}$ is zero.